# Compiling LWJGL jar on Mac, 'java.nio.FloatBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/FloatBuffer;'. Works in Eclipse, but not when exported

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl

I'm creating Shaders in my LWJGL engine, and I am able to successfully run the Jar from Eclipse using Java 8, however, when exported via Maven build, compiled for Mac and run on a Mac, will give off the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.FloatBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/FloatBuffer;`

Originally, I had tried to compile the Jar into a Mac Application file using install4j, but it cannot run the application due to this error. 
Again, the exact same Jar when run on a Windows works perfectly fine.

The Code which the error appears to originate from

```java
private static FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

protected void loadMatrix(int location, Matrix4f matrix){
        matrix.store(matrixBuffer);
        matrixBuffer.flip();
        GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(location, false, matrixBuffer);
    }
```

Error when run...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.FloatBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/FloatBuffer;
    at io.github.hydos.ginger.renderEngine.shaders.ShaderProgram.loadMatrix(ShaderProgram.java:96)
    at io.github.hydos.ginger.renderEngine.shaders.StaticShader.loadProjectionMatrix(StaticShader.java:65)
    at io.github.hydos.ginger.renderEngine.renderers.EntityRenderer.<init>(EntityRenderer.java:26)
    at io.github.hydos.ginger.renderEngine.renderers.MasterRenderer.<init>(MasterRenderer.java:51)
    at io.github.hydos.ginger.Example.main(Example.java:31)
    at io.github.hydos.ginger.Starter.main(Starter.java:6)
```

Despite this working normally when run through Eclipse, the Jar does not run on a Mac at all, whether executed through Terminal or by opening. Even though the Jar was compiled for Mac, it still works on Windows. I expected the Jar to run on a Mac, but I believe there is some kind of discrepancy within the JRE.

Edit: Pom.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>me.hydos</groupId>
    <artifactId>ginger</artifactId>
    <version>NIGHTLY</version>
    <name>gingerEngine</name>
    <description>an engine for 3d java game development</description>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <lwjgl.version>3.2.2</lwjgl.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>lwjgl-natives-linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os><family>unix</family></os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <lwjgl.natives>natives-linux</lwjgl.natives>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>lwjgl-natives-macos</id>
            <activation>
                <os><family>mac</family></os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <lwjgl.natives>natives-macos</lwjgl.natives>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>lwjgl-natives-windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os><family>windows</family></os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <lwjgl.natives>natives-windows</lwjgl.natives>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>io.github.hydos.ginger.Starter</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-assimp</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-bgfx</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-nanovg</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-nuklear</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-openal</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-openvr</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-par</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-assimp</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-bgfx</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-nanovg</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-nuklear</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-openal</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-openvr</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-par</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>${lwjgl.natives}</classifier>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-assimp</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-bgfx</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-glfw</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-nanovg</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-nuklear</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-openal</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-opengl</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-openvr</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-par</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lwjgl</groupId>
            <artifactId>lwjgl-stb</artifactId>
            <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
            <classifier>natives-macos</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Don't know if it will help resolve the problem - but I'm sure it can't hurt. Post your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: What version is the java actually used on the Mac?